# View moving from one end of screen to other

Tags: android

I need to create a view that is moving from one end of screen to other end at the bottom of screen.
Means like **in new channels flash news is moving contiguously at bottom**.Similar concept is what i want.
I dont know what *widget* is to be used.I tried **flipper** but in that only 1 textview is replacing by other only.I need it to move from one end to other and change the content.
Can anyone help?

I tried with the below mentioned answer using marquee..but still it is not moving..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label); 
      t.setSelected(true);
}
```

//xml

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >


<TextView
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:text="@string/hello_world"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
 android:singleLine="true"
/>
```

**it worked.
Problem was actually i gave a string which is very small (hello world) now i give a new lengthy string.so it worked**

Comment: Do you want to move text from right to left just like a news ticker?

Comment: @AmeerMoaaviah ya...like flash new..what should be used for that?any particular widget is there?or i need to use any custom views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

xml for `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

code for this `TextView`

If you want to make a ticker

```
textView.setSelected(true);
```

If you want to stop it

```
textView.setSelected(false);
```

*** *** **EDIT** ** **********

I assume that you are extending your activity from `ListActivity`. Do the following In your `onListItemClick`

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View row, int position, long id) {

    TextView textViewOne =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textViewOne.setSelected(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if(i!=position){
            View view = (View) parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.view);

            textViewOne = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            textViewOne.setSelected(false);

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: it is not working..means not moving.Anything else i have to do with coding??

Comment: I have made some change in the code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: no i am not extending anything.i created a new xml which consist of only that textview and class with setselected() but still not working

Comment: thnkz ...it worked.Problem was actually i gave a string which is very small (hello world) now i gave a new lengthy string.so it worked.

Answer (score 1):

just check it out :

xml file :

```
<TextView

android:id="@+id/myTextView"

android:ellipsize="marquee" 

android:singleLine="true"/>
```

in code :

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

tv.setSelected(true);
```

here you have to take textview as single line

Comment: ya this also worked.but actual issue was i was giving a small text string.so that is was not moving

Answer (score 0):

I don't totally understand what you want to achieve but apparently you have two options:

create your own view: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

or create some animation and use an existing view: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html